# Fixed Width Fonts - For user interface

Tags: fonts, font-face, font-size, webfonts

I would like to create a web application, where people can post messages to each other.

However I want to specify how many charachers can they enter, because of the message which will be displayed on the site after they've entered. And I'd like it not to look like a Coding font.

But if I'm using a random font, it is kinda bad, because it's 'W' is much wider than it's 'i'

This is why I'm searching for a font which is fixed width, or almost the same width.

I have found a lot in here: http://www.fontspace.com/category/fixed%20width

However there is nothing, which would look like a normal font. Every one is coder font :(

Can anyone suggest me a font which can be used for this? (I mean what facebook uses for advertisements, or google, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try to find it in this largest collection of good fonts: http://www.myfonts.com/search/monospaced/fonts/

I think [Orca Pro](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/v-design/orca-pro/) is a good solution of the problem described.

[image]